# QString: Remove first occurance of regular expression

Tags: regex, qt, qstring, qregexp

`QString` has a method `remove` that takes a `QRegExp`. It removes every occurrence of the regular expression.

Is there a way to remove only the first occurrence of the regular expression?

Answer to [QString replace only first occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024855/qstring-replace-only-first-occurrence) doesn't help. See comment from Akiva there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QString replace only first occurrence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024855/qstring-replace-only-first-occurrence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use next code:

```
QString message = "This is the original text";
QRegExp rx = QRegExp("is|he", Qt::CaseInsensitive);

if (message.contains(rx)){
    message = message.remove(rx.pos(0), rx.cap(0).size());
}
```

The final message is:

```
Th is the original text
```